# I run mysqld on Windows 10, how do I connect to its port from WSL

Tags: mysql, sockets, xampp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

`mysql` (for good reasons) tries very hard to connect to the socket file when the XAMPP mysql server is at 'localhost'. But since Win64 `mysqld` of course does not drop a socket file inside the Windows Subsystem for Linux filesytem, it can't connect through the socket file. How do I force it to use the port?

```
$ mysql --port=3306 -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directo
ry")
```

Nmap shows port 3306 is accessible.

```
$ nmap localhost -p 3306

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-25 09:58 DST
Problem binding to interface , errno: 92
socket_bindtodevice: Protocol not available
Problem binding to interface , errno: 92
socket_bindtodevice: Protocol not available
Problem binding to interface , errno: 92
socket_bindtodevice: Protocol not available
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0019s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

I'd rather not not bind mysqld to my outside network if I don't need to.

How do I tell the mysql software, "Look I know what you think, but please use port 3306, and not the socket"? Preferably I'd like to know how to tell the same to PHP too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved it, you need to add `--protocol=TCP`. Example:

```
$ mysql --protocol=TCP -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'henk'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Now it's simply a user/password problem on my side.

I'll edit in the setting for `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf`, `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini` once I figure out what the settings need to be.

Edit:

`sudo vim /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf`, under `[client]` comment out the socket line with a `#`, add a line that reads `protocol = TCP`. The path of this file might be different with an actual Oracle MySQL install, instead of MariaDB.

```
[mysql]
# socket = 3306
protocol = TCP
```

PHP's pdo_mysql/mysqli/mysqlnd will use the TCP protocol if you connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, this works around the localhost socket file / named-pipe heuristics.